# Error when compiling in Cygwin: "cannot run /bin/sh ./config.sub"

Tags: bash, cygwin, compile, autoconf

Premise, this is the first time I try to compile anything. I am using the Cygwin (64-bit) terminal on a Windows machine.

I am trying to compile some source files that came in a tarball.

I navigate to the directory where I unzipped the tarball, then enter

```
./configure
```

After a couple of seconds, the shell responds:

```
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh ./config.sub
```

config.log does not help clarify the issue:

```
## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2156: error: cannot run /bin/sh ./config.sub
```

I tried a couple of things. First of all, both config.sub and /bin/sh are there.

```
$ ./config.sub --help
Usage: ./config.sub [OPTION] CPU-MFR-OPSYS or ALIAS
[snip]

$ ls -l /bin/sh
-rwxr-xr-x 2 foo bar 739859 Jan 27  2017 /bin/sh
```

Second, the tarball is old (this is a 2013 release and it is the latest available. I prefer not to go into the details about what the code actually is, but if necessary I will, and I'm glad to provide more code snippets). After discovering what config.sub is, I tried to download the latest versions of config.sub and config.guess from Git. However, nothing changed.

I also tried to run the Cygwin terminal as Administrator.

The problem is not about CRLF/LF line endings:
[Files are saved in Unix format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGQsS.png)

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Check the line endings. See [Configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh](//stackoverflow.com/a/40296759)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post to reflect your comment. Unfortunately, that's not the issue. I *did* run into that issue when I downloaded the latest version of config.sub from Git, because I pasted it in... :D

Comment: try `autoreconf -ivf` to update the autoconf stuff to latest cygwin version

Comment: Thanks. I entered `autoreconf -ivf` and here is what came out: 

    $ autoreconf -ivf
          0 [main] sh 18596 fork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe', errno 13
    /usr/bin/autoreconf: fork: Permission denied
          0 [main] perl 14720 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'Fcntl         .dll' (0x3FD270000) is already occupied
    Can't fork, trying again in 5 seconds at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/General.pm

[and so on every 5 seconds forever]

Comment: tbh, I get this type of errors about "permissions" and "address spaces already occupied" also when I try to compile other stuff. I tried to compile GNU-parallel and ./configure gave me that type of error. So it's already a step forward.